# Activate router-link that has multi level nested routes with CRUD setup

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I trying to setup deep nesting like below, and I am kinda sure about we cannot use `exact` in `router-link` for nested routes.

```
<div id="app">
  <nav class="nav nav-main">
    <router-link exact to="/" class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Dashboard</router-link>
    <router-link to="/projects" class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Projects</router-link>
  </nav>

  <div class="parent-content">
    <h4>Content for Parent goes here</h4>
  </div>

  <router-view>
    <nav class="nav nav-main">
      <router-link :to="'/projects/' + $route.params.projectId" class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Deals</router-link>
      <router-link :to="'/projects/' + $route.params.projectId + '/commitments/'" class="nav-link" activeClass="active">Commitments</router-link>
    </nav>
    <router-view>
      <div class="child-content">
        <h4>Content for Child goes here</h4>
      </div>
    </router-view>
  </router-view>
</div>
```

My Route:

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/projects',
    component: Projects
  },
  {
    path: '/projects/:id',
    name: 'projects-detail',
    component: ProjectDetails,
    children: [
      // DEALS
      {
        path: '/projects/:projectId/deals',
        component: Deals
      },
      {
        path: '/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/details',
        component: DealDetails
      },
      // COMMITMENTS
      {
        path: '/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/commitments/:commitmentId/edit',
        component: CommitmentEdit
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

With the above setup, I need to activate router-links, when the route is:
`/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/details` then activate `Deals`
`/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/commitments/:commitmentId/edit` then activate `Commitments`

Comment: You could try to count passed parameters. If you pass 2 args then its Deals page, if 3 then its Commitments. You can get parameters by using $route.params, then just bind class depending on these values.

Comment: Your inner `<router-view>` is not closed properly like `</router-view>`, It seems syntax error, Might be live demo would be easy for us to answer.

Comment: thanks for noting  that, I have just added minimum working code and its fine in my actual code :)

Answer (score 9):

I think you have not another `<router-view></router-view>` inside  `ProjectDetails` component add this and try.

Also remove `/projects/:projectId` from all child path as you have already in parent path `path: '/projects/:id',`

So final you route would be

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/projects',
    component: Projects
  },
  {
    path: '/projects/:id',
    component: ProjectDetails,
    children : [
      // DEALS
      {
        path: 'deals/:dealId/details',//path will be /projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/details
        component: DealDetails
      },
      {
        path: 'deals',.// path will be /projects/:projectId/deals
        component: Deals
      },
      // COMMITMENTS
      {
        path: '/deals/:dealId/commitments/:commitmentId/edit/',
        component: CommitmentEdit
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here is working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/chyLjpv0/16/

Read more about [**child path**](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html).

If you need not and component depended on parent dont make it as child use directly as root path like

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Dashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/projects',
    component: Projects
  },
  {
    path: '/projects/:id',
    component: ProjectDetails,
   },
    // DEALS
    {
      path: '/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/details',
      component: DealDetails
    },
    {
      path: '/projects/:projectId/deals',
      component: Deals
    },
    // COMMITMENTS
    {
      path: '/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/commitments/:commitmentId/edit/',
      component: CommitmentEdit
    }
]
```

Working fiddle for this : https://jsfiddle.net/chyLjpv0/17/

Class `router-link-exact-active` is already working in this example : https://jsfiddle.net/chyLjpv0/18/ to display link as active

**In your edit**

Why you put `<router-view>` inside `<router-view>`. Outer is only working as it is being replaced and inner `<router-view>` is worthless. Use `<router-view>` in parent component for child component.

Also your inner `<router-view>` is not closed properly like `</router-view>`

Comment: In my question, I forgot to add `<router-view></router-view>` in project details component but I have updated my question now, I have just two `router-link` which should get active and in-active when as mentioned in my question:  `/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/details` then activate Deals
`/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/commitments/:commitmentId/edit` then activate Commitments

Comment: @Syed : what do you mean by activate ? do you want like this https://jsfiddle.net/chyLjpv0/18/

Comment: I mean that I like to add `activeClass="active"` to `router-link` when the route is at `/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/details` then activate Deals and `/projects/:projectId/deals/:dealId/commitments/:commitmentId‌​/edit` then activate Commitments

Comment: @Syed : why you need this if `router-link-exact-active` is already working in this example : https://jsfiddle.net/chyLjpv0/18/ ?

Comment: for discussion sake let's forget `activeClass="active"` and use what's default `router-link-exact-active`. The problem is I have only 2 tab/nav items. So, this need have `router-link-exact-active` or `active` class, condition are as mentioned in above comment.

Comment: @Syed : please share you live demo/snippet/fiddle to better understand and what you expected. Why you put `<router-view>` inside `<router-view>` outer is only working as it is being replaced and inner `<router-view>` is worthless

Comment: thanks for helping me, though your solution did not help I am rewarding bounty as you gave it a try. If you are still interested to solve this issue, I can walk you through the code and we can figure this thing out. My skype ID is syed_haroon, ping me when ever you have time.

Comment: @Syed : Can you make a live demo of your code ? and share what you are getting and what you want, as this ans not helped to you here in SO.

Comment: as of now it's not deployed anywhere, it's in my local system and kinda huge setup with multiple team members, for now skype could be the only way. The app can still survive without the fix, I was just curious to solve it, that's it. If you are curious as I am, we can catch up, my skype ID is syed_haroon ping me when ever you are free. thanks