# Vue Router sub components

Tags: vue.js, router

I have a website consisting of a Sitemap like this:

```
Home
About
Golf
 -- Course one
 -- Course two
Work
 -- Work one
 -- Work two
Contact
```

So Work.vue is laid out like this

```
<header></header>
<carousel></carousel>
<work-one</work-one>
<work-two></work-two>
<footer></footer>
```

My question in my main navigation above if I click the sub navigation item `Work two` how I then go to the Work page and scroll to the Work two component or even better if the `work two` component would load first and the `work one` component would load under it.

Really hope I am making sense but basically I want to be able to link to specific parts of a vue Page component which contains other components also.

Thanks

Comment: if you want child component check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074043/2815635

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this doesn't really have much to do with Vue or Vue router as it does simple html.

You can use anchor tags for this (http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm):

Simply put, in each components html have something like

```
<a name="work-one"></a>
```

Then, when you want to link to that specific component on that page, you can do:

```
<a href="yoursite.com/your-main-page-link#work-one">Link Text</a>
```

Or the Vue Router way:

```
<router-link to="yoursite.com/your-main-page-link#work-one">Link Text</router-link>
```