# Child route component not rendering in vue js

Tags: vue.js, routes, components, vue-component

i have defined route like

```
{
        path:'/admins',
        name:'admin.admins',
        component: Admin,
        children: [
            {
              path:'add',
              name:'admin.add',
              component:addAdmin
            },
            {
              path:'edit/:id',
              name:'admin.edit',
              component:editAdmin
            }
        ]
    }
```

if i declare children route outside children like

```
{
        path:'/admins',
        name:'admin.admins',
        component: Admin
    },
    {
      path:'/add',
      name:'admin.add',
      component:addAdmin
    },
    {
      path:'/edit/:id',
      name:'admin.edit',
      component:editAdmin
    }
```

everything works fine but while visiting child routes, url in browser changes but component do not load. Only parent compenent shows up while visiting parent and child path.
I am calling routes like

```
<router-link :to="{ name:'admin.add' }"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Admin</router-link>
```

Comment: share live demo and how you are calling these routes ?

Comment: question updated. please check it

Comment: did you added  `router-view` for parent component ?  Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074043/2815635)

Comment: Please share live demo or at least `component: Admin,`  ?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

When using nested routes, the child component is dependent on the parent component. To render the child component while visiting the child path you must call

`<router-view></router-view>` inside the parent component too.

If your path is independent, do not make it as a child. If you register the child route keep putting `<router-view></router-view>` on the parent component (on any nested level).

If you start nested route with `/` it will be treated as root path.
[Read more](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html)

Answer (score 0):

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html

According to the doc, your child route will be render in your nested `<router-view></router-view>`. Check you have the correct setup.

Comment: i have done that.