# Child routes are still only loading parent component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

So I'm trying to create a a settings page that has child routes. For example, I want to have /settings/user, then /settings/branches, etc. However, everytime I load /settings or any of its child routes it only shows the parent Settings component.

Here is my routes.js file

```js
// Imports
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Store from './store';

// Set to use
Vue.use(VueRouter);

// Views
import Home from './views/Home/';
import UserIndex from './views/UserIndex';

// Grab Routes
import Settings from './routes/Settings'

// Create our routes
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: '/users',
    name: 'users.index',
    component: UserIndex,
  },
].concat(Settings);
```

Here is my Settings.js (which is later contacted in my main routes folder)

```js
// Routes for /Settings/
import Settings from '../views/Settings/';
import Branches from '../views/Settings/Branches';

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/settings',
    name: 'settings',
    component: Settings,
    children: [
      {
        name: 'branches',
        path:'branches',
        component: Branches
      }
    ]
  }
]
export default routes;
```

/views/settings/Branches.vue

```js
<template>
    <div>
      <p>Branches page</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {

    }
  }
</script>
```

/views/settings/index.vue

```js
<template>
    <div>
      <p>settings page</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    components: {

    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247097/child-route-component-not-rendering-in-vue-js/50265765#50265765

Answer (score 0):

Just include `<router-view></router-view>` to settings page, so it can render its own children. Then you can navigate to it through `/settings/branches` link.

[Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

```
<template>
    <div>
      <p>Settings page</p>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: The second recommendation is not correct. From the docs: `Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path.`