# How to configure vue 3 router children properly to have nested routes working as expected?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a vue 2 app using vue 3 router. I want to have a route like /user and within that /user/profile and /user/settings. So, I configured my vue router.js file as

`router.js`

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import User from "../components/User";
import Settings from "../components/Settings";
import Profile from "../components/Profile";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/user",
      name: "user",
      component: User,
      children: [
        {
          path: "/settings",
          name: "settings",
          component: Settings
        },
        {
          path: "/profile",
          name: "profile",
          component: Profile
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

`User.vue`

```
<template>
  <h1>User</h1>
</template>
```

`Settings.vue`

```
<template>
  <h1>Settings</h1>
</template>
```

`Profile.vue`

```
<template>
  <h1>Settings</h1>
</template>
```

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Whenever I am visiting `/user`, the User.vue is rendered but when I am trying to visit `/user/profile` or `/user/settings`, nothing is rendered in the DOM. I followed [Child route component not rendering in vue js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247097/child-route-component-not-rendering-in-vue-js) and [Activate router-link that has multi level nested routes with CRUD setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987275/activate-router-link-that-has-multi-level-nested-routes-with-crud-setup) but no luck. What I want is User.vue should be rendered on `/user` route and only the contents of `Profile.vue` should be rendered when we are in `/user/profile` route. I tried to include `<router-view />` in `User.vue` but I am getting both `User.vue` and `Profile.vue` contents in `/user/profile`. I am attaching codesandbox link to see it in live and to get a better understanding as I am not sure how to set it up in SO.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sky-3wvhqr?file=/App.vue:0-354

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UserParent.vue`

```
<template>
  <router-view />
</template>
```

`router.js`

```
routes: [
  {
    path: "/user",
    component: UserParent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        name: "user",
        component: User
      },
      {
        path: "/settings",
        name: "settings",
        component: Settings
      },
      {
        path: "/profile",
        name: "profile",
        component: Profile
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: As I mentioned, when I am doing <router-view /> in parent component, the parent content also showing up

Comment: Sorry, I obviously didn't read properly! I have updated my answer.

Comment: But this doesn't serve the usage of children right? What if I need to include a meta property that checks auth for each sub route under user? I need to add it for each and every route

Comment: Ok then in that case have the parent route render nothing but `<router-view />`, and add { path: '/', component: UserHome } to your children and move everything from your current User template to UserHome. Does that make sense?

From the docs: 'Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.' https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: It worked when I just entered as path: settings instead of path: /settings. Thank you so much @Daniel